# Stop awk processing when duplicate is found

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file that has duplicates. Intention is to check if there are any duplicates ...  and stop processing incase there is a duplicate, so even if one duplicate record exists, we want to just exist awk processing. How an we do that ? The following code completely processes.

Thank you.

````
awk -F'|' '{same[$1]++} END  {if (same[$1]) 
               { print "Found duplicate"; }
            else
               { print "No Duplicate Found" } 
           }' pipe.txt```


Pipe.txt

Jim Smith|123 Any Street|Boston|US|02134
Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130
Jim Smith|123 Any Street|Boston|UK|02134
Bret Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130
Bret Lee|123 Any Street|Boston|US|021340
Shen Lee|123 Any Street|Boston|US|021341
````

Comment: Is duplicate based on `name` only? or should be looked at streetname/city too ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F'|' 'seen[$1]++{f=1; exit} END{print (f ? "" : "No ") "duplicate found"; exit f}' file
duplicate found
$ echo $?
1

$ seq 5 | awk -F'|' 'seen[$1]++{f=1; exit} END{print (f ? "" : "No ") "duplicate found"; exit f}'
No duplicate found
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Some explanation about `exit`: The `exit` commands terminates the processing of the input files and skips directly to the `END` statement. If `exit` is used in an `END` statement, it exits awk.